# Node.js API requests randomly stopping

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios, discord.js

This is my first project, yes the code is bad, please be nice!
I'm working on a Discord Bot, which requests Game APIs for a whole Guild. First I get all the Ids for a guild into an array and then I make a get request for every Id.
My problem is, that the request just randomly stops after some time (always different), and I don't know why. It's also not giving an error.
I've already tried to run it from another program, change the package I'm using, look that the key can be used, but in the end, everything is the same.

```
    while (guildmembers[i2] != undefined) {
      console.log(guildmembers[i2])
      let url = 'https://api.hypixel.net/player?key=' + APIkey
      let Guildmembersuuid = guildmembers[i2]
      let profilelurl = url + '&uuid=' + Guildmembersuuid
      const TESTguildPlayerinfos = await axios.get(profilelurl)
      console.log(TESTguildPlayerinfos)
      i2++
    }
```

If I did anything wrong with the post or didn't give enough information please tell me!
Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: If it doesn't throw any error, how do you know it has stopped ? Need more info here, the code looks fine to me.

Comment: It's not finished with the Array.

Comment: How do you know that ? Does the code get hung ?

Comment: Oh yea, It's not doing anything after that anymore.
In my testing, I logged the Id before the await and then 'done' after. It logs the id but stops at the await and does nothing after that.

Comment: Yes, I get results before. The Loop has to do it for each is the array and it just randomly halts at the await for one.

Comment: How are you calling this snippet? I would guess the `axios.get` is returning an error that is being swallowed.

Comment: Ok, my best guess here would be that the server is not responding for some of your requests (it can be anything from a network issue to server being slow to response). My advice would be to add a network timeout to your axiom request settings which would timeout your request after a max limit.

Comment: Then handle the timeout gracefully

Comment: Sounds like rate limiting maybe? Does the API have documented limits?

Answer (score 0):

try using Promise.all(),which takes an array of promises and then put a catch block afterwards to see if there is any problem.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are hitting the Hypixel throttling limits - you need to be more careful with your requests. As it stands, they will stop you at 120 requests/minute. You either need to manually throttle yourself like one member in the thread mentioned (waiting .5 seconds between any call to the API to ensure you don't overflow the limit) or insert a cache in between so that calls don't actually always land on the Hypixel backend.

https://hypixel.net/threads/api-request-limit.815723/